# Running python flask application on repl gives error

Tags: python, flask, replit

I am running a python flask application in replit and when it try to access the url, i am getting the following message

```
  Hmmmm.... We Couldn't Reach Your Repl Make sure your repl has a port open and is ready to receive HTTP traffic.
```

How to solve this error

[image]

Comment: Try adding `host=0.0.0.0` to your `app.run()` or similar call. Also share your repl with us.

Comment: Already added host to app.run(). How can i share the repl. Im new to this

Comment: A screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you're running the flask server on a used port.
Try to set a different port:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

or

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```